# How to iterate through a bunch of streams and read one element at a time?

Tags: java, sorting, iterator

I have a stream class which consists of sorted in ascending order.

```
class Stream {
    boolean hasNext();
    int peek(); 
    int next();
}
```

I need to write a program to merge multiple streams and print out the elements that exist more than a number of times in different streams without repeating.

This is how I design it with pseudo code:

```
// print out numbers with occurance greater than (k).
void mergeStreams(List<Stream> streams, int k) {
    int minCount = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    List<Stream> minStreams;

    loop through each stream and read in elements on head {
        if (streams.size() < k) return;
        if (!stream.hasNext()) {
            streams.remove(stream); continue;
        }
        if (stream.peek() <= min) {
            if (stream.peek() == min) {
                minCount++;
            }
            else {
                minStreams = new ArrayList<Stream>();
                min = stream.peek();
                minCount = 1;

            }
            minStreams.add(stream);
        }
        if last stream in streams {
            if (minCount >= k) {
                System.out.println(min);
                for (Stream s : minStreams) {
                    if (s.hasNext()) s.next();
                    else streams.remove(s);
            }
        }
}
```

Problem is I don't know how exactly to iterate through streams and read on element at a time and hence the pseudo code part. Plus, I am not sure if `streams.remove(s)` at the bottom of the code really deletes stream `s` from original list of Streams since it has been added to new list `minStreams`. I can really use some advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove elements from a list while iterating over it, you should use [Iterator.remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--). You'll also need a `while` loop around the whole thing to check more than one value.

```
void mergeStreams(List<Stream> streams, int k) {
    while (streams.size() >= k) { // each loop checks one value (the current minimum)
        int minCount = 0;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        List<Stream> minStreams = new ArrayList<>();

        Iterator<Stream> streamIter = streams.iterator(); // supports remove during iteration
        while (streamIter.hasNext()) {
            Stream stream = streamIter.next();
            if (!stream.hasNext()) {
                streamIter.remove(); // remove stream from original list
                continue;
            }
            if (stream.peek() <= min) {
                if (stream.peek() == min) {
                    minCount++;
                } else {
                    minStreams = new ArrayList<>();
                    min = stream.peek();
                    minCount = 1;
                }
                minStreams.add(stream);
            }
        }
        if (minCount >= k) { // runs after iterating over streams
            System.out.println(min);
        }
        for (Stream s : minStreams) { // must advance past the current min value
            if (s.hasNext()) {
                s.next();
            } else {
                streams.remove(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also fixed a bug where the streams in `minStreams` didn't advance past the minimum value when `minCount < k`, so it would get stuck on that value.

Comment: Using a while loop inside a for loop, you are iterating through one stream from beginning to the end. What I wanted is to look at each stream's head in one pass and move on the the next round.

Comment: Ah, I get what it's doing now. Updated my answer.